# Charts added to RDLC report via designer in Visual Studio 2017 won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, rdlc

When I add new `Report.rdlc` file to my project and open it with XML editor the top of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Adding a table in designer works fine and allows me to [render it to pdf like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZOVF.png)

Problems start when I add any chart in designer. The top part of the file changes to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

**2008 => 2016** and some additional tags like `<ReportSections>` are being added.

After that the report wont render at all.

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: "An error occurred during local report processing".

ReportProcessingException: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
```

I'm using **Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime** (12.0.2.2402) in my MVC web application. Controller returns reports as files without SQL Server Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the report viewer to the latest and it should work: `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80`

Answer (score -1):

You can uninstall Microsoft.ReportViewer and install Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms Instead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o1Bv.png)